# How do I view the value of a secret via kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way I can view the secret via kubectl?

Given the secret name, and the data (file?) how do I view the raw result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution relies on `jq`.

```
secretName="example-secret-name"
secKeyName="example.key"
kubectl get secret "$secretName" -o json | jq -r ".[\"data\"][\"$secKeyName\"]" | base64 -d
```